# cron job doesn't work .. why?

Tags: php, cron

How are you?

I can't run cron job

this is my url: http://twitter.trips-world.com/updateing.php

I want it every * * * * *

I test this : /home/xxxxxx/public_html/twitter/updateing.php    but doesn't work

please help me

you mean like this [image]

Comment: Shouldn't the stars be before the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please list the output of console: php -f /home/xxxxxx/public_html/twitter/updateing.php command.
Also verify your cronjob entry on test server. Try to add full path of script, or put an "cd" to path of the script before calling the execution of script itself. Verify chmod of cronjob and owner (chown). Provide more details and you'll be helped. And I think you should start with posting the source of your script.

Comment: I'm sorry , I doesn't understand , my english is bad , can you explain it ?

Answer (score 1):

enter code hereTry command as follow,

```
curl http://www.mydomain.com/updateing.php
```

update:

> I want it every * * * * *

You can set up cron to execute every minute just putting * on each available options.
Please do not forget to check cron policy of hosting service providers.

For more details check

http://lamplightdevelopment.com/blog/post/id/using-cron-curl-to-monitor-the-status-of-your-site

http://drupal.org/cron

Comment: hostgator reseller you think the cron job is blocked